# Looping through stored procedure results to create string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns two columns like this;

[image]

I want to know if it's possible for me to create a comma delimited string from the iTypeID column of the result set.  I'm just not sure how to loop through that result set to create the string, i'd want the string to just end up as

```
@sqlString = '1,2,4,11,14'
```

as my parameter value.  The stored procedure call that produces the above table is;

```
exec cfn_PlanningGoalGetType 0,'xmlString'
```

don't know if that helps or is clear enough but any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Str varchar(100) 
SELECT @Str = COALESCE(@Str + ', ', '') + CAST(iTypeID AS varchar(5)) 
FROM TableName

Select @Str
```

Comment: this would take me executing the stored procedure into a temp table right?  just want to be sure i can't somehow avoid/get around doing that, but i agree with your suggestion, thank you

Answer (score 2):

This could create table variable to insert data from sproc and then select output into one line string.

```
DECLARE TABLE @tmpBus
(
   iTypeId INT,
   Desc INT
)

INSERT INTO @tmpBus
EXEC cfn_PlanningGoalGetType 0,'xmlString'

DECLARE @CodeNameString varchar(100)

SELECT 
   @CodeNameString = STUFF( (SELECT ',' + iTypeID
                             FROM @tmpBus
                             ORDER BY Sort
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')
```

Comment: thanks for your help! with this and humptys answer above this will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Here's two different options for your actual use case I'd go with Coalesce or my version without:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO Test (Id)
VALUES (1),(4),(7),(15)


declare @val nvarchar(max)
set  @val=''

select @val=@val +',' + cast(id as nvarchar) from test

select substring(@val,2,len(@vaL))
```

Another option is to build an Aggregator which is useful if your aggregating your results, or you want to return a delimited column in a result set. I've had to do this when I want to return a 1>N relationship but for paging in a UI we want to only return a small subset of the data. Imagine we want to return 10 contacts and the custom tags that a user defined on each contact...

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize = 8000)]
public struct StringConcat : IBinarySerialize
{
    private System.Collections.Generic.List<string> values;

    public void Init()
    {
        this.values = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString value)
    {
        if (!value.IsNull)
        {
            this.values.Add(value.Value);
        }
    }

    public void Merge(StringConcat value)
    {

        this.values.AddRange(value.values.ToArray());
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        return new SqlString(string.Join(", ", this.values.ToArray()));
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        int itemCount = r.ReadInt32();
        this.values = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(itemCount);
        for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)
        {
            this.values.Add(r.ReadString());
        }
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(this.values.Count);
        foreach (string s in this.values)
        {
            w.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

You would then run this as:

```
select dbo.stringcontact(id),someotherfield 
from mytable group by someotherfield
```